# My computer force pushes on git without asking me

Tags: git, github

Everything is in the  title. My computer force pushes and my collaborators can't push after me.
It's starting to be a big problem, does anyone know about this problem?

Comment: Please may you share the git commands used and their output? -- Do you have an alias which force pushes? What do you mean by the collaborators _can't push_? Force pushing doesn't prevent others from pushing too.

Comment: It would be useful to see what you do git-wise, *and* then what your collaborators do...

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if what is happening is that you are pushing, and since they don't have your commit in their local branch, they can't push

```
Original -- Your Commit - Your other commit
         \- Your colleague's commit
```

You colleague should be able to do something like this

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/branchname
# and now they will have your commit in their branch because you pushed first
git push origin branchname # now they can push because their local branch has everything origin has and more
```

I find it really helpful to use `gitk` and look at it before and after every commit, fetch, and push, to see how all this fits together.  If there is another problem, and you post a picture of gitk, I am sure somebody can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: That is just a guess though, so please comment if you think that is not the problem, and I'll try to make another guess

Comment: I think you're right that this is what is happening. Once we see the collaborators error messages, we'll know.